# SQL Server: INSERT INTO 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert-into

When I add a record into the `PERSONS` table, an `ID` column is auto incremented (identity).

I need this ID to insert a record into the `ADDRESS` table, so I will be able to join both of them.

Does anyone know how I can get this `ID` to use in the second statement when I have multiple rows to append?

Basically it would append one row and use the ID to append the row in the other table.

I would like to avoid to loop each record to do this.

Thank you in advance.

```
INSERT INTO PERSONS (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
    SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
    FROM CONTACTS

INSERT INTO ADDRESS (PERSON_ID)
    SELECT ID 
    FROM PERSONS
```

Comment: One method is to use a trigger.

Comment: There's a pretty standard pattern using the MERGE statement, or using the OUTPUT statement to a temp table and inserting into the child table from that.

Comment: In your first insert, you are inserting multiple rows i assume... and you want to insert these same rows (the ID from Persons table) tot he address table? If it's a single record then it's manageable, otherwise I'm with @GordonLinoff and would use a trigger. Really just use a trigger anyway since that's what it's for.

Comment: @scsimon - `OUTPUT INSERTED ... INTO` is for this exact and only purpose, so by that logic they should use that.

Comment: Yea @MartinSmith but there are [problems with MERGE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) that has been documented with Microsoft and i'm not willing to bet more haven't arised.

Comment: Why are so many people of the belief that MERGE is needed here anyway?

Comment: Hey marc_s, I didn't post here to get my English corrected!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INSERT ... OUTPUT INSERTED ... INTO`

```
INSERT @PERSONS
       (FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id
INTO @ADDRESS
SELECT *
FROM   @CONTACTS;
```

Or if your needs are more complex another possibility is a merge statement

```
DECLARE @CONTACTS table ( FIRST_NAME  varchar(50) , LAST_NAME varchar(50))
DECLARE @PERSONS table  (Id int identity , FIRST_NAME  varchar(50) , LAST_NAME varchar(50))
DECLARE @ADDRESS table  (PERSON_ID int)

INSERT @CONTACTS VALUES ('FIRST_NAME1' , 'LAST_NAME2'),  ('FIRST_NAME1' , 'LAST_NAME2');

MERGE @PERSONS t
using @CONTACTS s
on
t.FIRST_NAME = s.FIRST_NAME 
AND t.LAST_NAME = s.LAST_NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME ) Values (s.FIRST_NAME , s.LAST_NAME)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id into @ADDRESS;
```

Table PERSONS

```
select * from @PERSONS
Id          FIRST_NAME                                         LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1           FIRST_NAME1                                        LAST_NAME2
2           FIRST_NAME1                                        LAST_NAME2
```

Table ADDRESS

```
SELECT * from @ADDRESS
PERSON_ID
-----------
1
2
```

Comment: I don't see any requirement stated in the question for insert if not exists and MERGE rather than a plain `INSERT ... OUTPUT`

Comment: When you are inserting in batch, you cannot get the Identity created. An option creates a Trigger, but some cases it is not an option. On the merge statement you can get the output to use.

Comment: The output clause exists on insert too.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Not really used with Merge and Triggers. I tried OUTPUT Inserted but it didn't return me the result I wanted. I will figure  something out of all this.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize answer that was given by @GordonLinoff and @scsimon I created a small [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c29e6/12). You can check full Microsoft guide for triggers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql).

**[DDL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**:

`CREATE TABLE CONTACTS (
  FIRST_NAME  varchar(50) 
  , LAST_NAME varchar(50)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE PERSONS (
  Id int IDENTITY(1,1)
  , FIRST_NAME  varchar(50) 
  , LAST_NAME varchar(50)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS (
  PERSON_ID int
);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AI_Persons_PersonAddress ON PERSONS
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ADDRESS (PERSON_ID) SELECT Id FROM inserted
END`

**[DML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766(v=sql.110).aspx)**:

`INSERT INTO CONTACTS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES('Bob', 'White');
INSERT INTO CONTACTS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES('Tom', 'Black');
INSERT INTO PERSONS (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM CONTACTS;

SELECT * FROM ADDRESS;`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Not really used with Triggers. I tried OUTPUT Inserted but it didn't return me the result I wanted. I will figure something out of all this.